# What is the meaning of "not on my account"?

Tags: meaning

Peter just met Regina

> Regina: Mine's Regina Lampert.
>
> Peter: Is there a Mr. Lampert?
>
> Regina: Yes.
>
> Peter: Good for you.
>
> Regina: No, it isn't. I'm getting a divorce.
>
> Peter: Please, **not on my account**.
>
> Regina: No. I don't really love him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regrettably, a quick Internet search did not discover the etymology of the phrase, that actually surprised me.

"Not on my account" or any similar phrase means, "not because of me" or "not because of anything I did," etc.

It's a reference to personal accountability (literally, "you will not find that in my account").  The phrase may have come recently (within hundreds of years) due to the use of accounting books to establish personal responsibility for financial matters.  More anciently it may have derived from Biblical references such as:

> If he hath wronged thee, or oweth thee ought, put that on mine account;

From the book of Philemon chapter 1, verse 18.